# how to assign css class to a php varible inside an html string?

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

i have to use a php variable inside an html string, i'm using woocommerce and the varibale is $cannot_ship

```
echo wp_kses_post( 
    apply_filters( 
        'woocommerce_cart_no_shipping_available_html', 
        sprintf( esc_html__( 'We\'re Sorry, "'.$cannot_ship.'" in your cart can\'t be shipped for %s.', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '<strong>' . esc_html( $formatted_destination ) . '</strong>' ) 
    ) 
);
```

please guide how to add a class to this variable.

Comment: You can not “add a class to a variable” in HTML, you can only add classes to _elements_. So if you want the value of `$cannot_ship` and _only_ that to get a special formatting or something like that, then you will need to wrap it into an HTML element first.

Comment: can you tell me how would i do that

Comment: What exactly do you need to know? Putting a `<span>` or something into the string you already have there, doesn’t sound like it could be much of a problem …? (Whether WP _allows_ you to use HTML in this place, or will convert it to plain text - now that would be a different question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assign value to a new variable to the $cannot_ship 
something like this `$cannot_ship = '<span class="video-duration" style="color: red;font-family: roboto;font-weight: bold;">'.substr($cannot_ship, 0, -2). '</span>';`
and then change `esc_html__`
to just `__` and you will have your html tag my case i used span the problem was caused by `esc_html__` it was removing my html tag.